# Error building _CompileToNative. What is wrong Xamarin Studio? It won't build ANY Xamarin.Forms projects for iOS giving this strange error

Tags: build, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Any idea is appreciated!

I reinstalled Yosemite, Xcode 6.4 and Xamarin Studio from scratch.
Still it won't build even empty Xamarin.Forms app for iOS.

Error: Error building target _CompileToNative: startIndex + length cannot exceed length of string.

```
Building Solution: proba7 (Debug)

Building: proba7 (Debug)

Build started 12.8.2015. 16:03:52.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/proba7/proba7.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Initial Properties:
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0x0:0x0
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.pXaHYrz3LQ/Render
AssemblyName = proba7
BuildingInsideVisualStudio = true
Configuration = Debug
ConsolePause = false
CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents = <SolutionConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Project="{4259FEB1-7A13-4C36-A192-BC5C0E66D555}" AbsolutePath="/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/proba7/proba7.csproj">Debug|AnyCPU</ProjectConfiguration>
</SolutionConfiguration>
DebugSymbols = true
DebugType = full
DefineConstants = DEBUG;
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH = /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib:/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
ErrorReport = prompt
GTK2_RC_FILES = /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/gtkrc.mac-yosemite
HOME = /Users/rasulo
LOGNAME = rasulo
MONO_GAC_PREFIX = /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources
MSBuildBinPath = /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5
MSBuildExtensionsPath = /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/xbuild
MSBuildExtensionsPath32 = /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/xbuild
MSBuildExtensionsPath64 = /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/xbuild
MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets = Build
MSBuildProjectDirectory = /Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/proba7
MSBuildProjectExtension = .csproj
MSBuildProjectFile = proba7.csproj
MSBuildProjectFullPath = /Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/proba7/proba7.csproj
MSBuildProjectName = proba7
MSBuildThisFile = proba7.csproj
MSBuildThisFileDirectory = /Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/proba7/
MSBuildThisFileDirectoryNoRoot = Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/proba7/
MSBuildThisFileExtension = .csproj
MSBuildThisFileFullPath = /Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/proba7/proba7.csproj
MSBuildThisFileName = proba7
MSBuildToolsPath = /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5
MSBuildToolsRoot = /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono
MSBuildToolsVersion = 4.0
Optimize = false
OS = Unix
OutputPath = bin\Debug
OutputType = Library
PATH = /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources:/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR = 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH = /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/pkgconfig:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/share/pkgconfig:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/pkgconfig
Platform = AnyCPU
ProjectGuid = {4259FEB1-7A13-4C36-A192-BC5C0E66D555}
ProjectTypeGuids = {786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
RootNamespace = proba7
SHELL = /bin/bash
SolutionDir = /Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/
SolutionFilename = proba7.sln
SolutionName = proba7
SolutionPath = /Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/proba7.sln
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tLJxvT2tdR/Listeners
TargetFrameworkProfile = Profile111
TargetFrameworkVersion = v4.5
TMPDIR = /var/folders/1n/kb_hzqwn7hdfcsz330v1vfkc0000gn/T/
UseHostCompilerIfAvailable = false
USER = rasulo
WarningLevel = 4
XPC_FLAGS = 0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME = com.xamarin.monodevelop.100000

...
...
...

    Target _CompileAppManifest:
    Target _CompileAppManifest needs to be built as output file 'bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/proba7.iOS.app/Info.plist' does not exist.
    Task "CompileAppManifest"
        Using task CompileAppManifest from Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.CompileAppManifest, Xamarin.iOS.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
        CompileAppManifest Task
          AppBundleName: proba7.iOS
          AppBundleDir: bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/proba7.iOS.app
          AppManifest: Info.plist
          Architecture: i386, x86_64
          AssemblyName: proba7.iOS
          BundleIdentifier: com.companyname.proba7
          DefaultSdkVersion: 8.4
          IsAppExtension: False
          IsWatchApp: False
          IsWatchExtension: False
          PartialAppManifests: <null>
          Platform: iPhoneSimulator
    Done executing task "CompileAppManifest"
    Task "RemoveDir"
        Using task RemoveDir from Microsoft.Build.Tasks.RemoveDir, Xamarin.iOS.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    Done executing task "RemoveDir"
    Done building target "_CompileAppManifest" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj".

Done building target "_CompileAppManifest" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "_CreateAppBundle" depends on it.
Building target "_GetNativeExecutableName" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "_CreateAppBundle" depends on it.

    Target _GetNativeExecutableName:
    Task "GetNativeExecutableName"
        Using task GetNativeExecutableName from Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.GetNativeExecutableName, Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks, Version=1.0.5694.24852, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
        GetNativeExecutableName Task
          AppManifest: bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/proba7.iOS.app/Info.plist
    Done executing task "GetNativeExecutableName"
    Done building target "_GetNativeExecutableName" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj".

Done building target "_GetNativeExecutableName" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "_CreateAppBundle" depends on it.
Building target "_CompileToNative" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "_CreateAppBundle" depends on it.
Building target "_CompileEntitlements" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "_CompileToNative" depends on it.
Target _CompileEntitlements skipped due to false condition: '$(ComputedPlatform)' == 'iPhone' Or '$(CodesignEntitlements)' != ''
Done building target "_CompileEntitlements" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "_CompileToNative" depends on it.

    Target _CompileToNative:
    Target _CompileToNative needs to be built as output file 'bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/proba7.iOS.app/proba7iOS' does not exist.
    Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj".

: error : Error building target _CompileToNative: startIndex + length cannot exceed length of string.
Parameter name: length
Error building target _CompileToNative: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex + length cannot exceed length of string.
Parameter name: length
  at System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider, Boolean tryParse, System.Double& result, System.Exception& exc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Single.TryParse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider, System.Single& result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Single.TryParse (System.String s, System.Single& result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ConditionFactorExpression.CanEvaluateToNumber (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ConditionRelationalExpression.BoolEvaluate (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ConditionParser.ParseAndEvaluate (System.String condition, Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskBatchingImpl.Execute (IBuildTask buildTask, TaskExecutionMode taskExecutionMode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskBatchingImpl.Run (IBuildTask buildTask, TaskExecutionMode taskExecutionMode, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskBatchingImpl.Build (IBuildTask buildTask, TaskExecutionMode taskExecutionMode, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetBatchingImpl.RunTargetWithBucket (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 bucket, Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target target, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetBatchingImpl.Run (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target target, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetBatchingImpl.Build (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target target, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target.DoBuild (System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "_CreateAppBundle" depends on it.
Done building target "_CreateAppBundle" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets"); "Build" depends on it.
Done building target "Build" in project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj" ("/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets").
Done building project "/Users/rasulo/Projects/proba7/iOS/proba7.iOS.csproj".-- FAILED

Target perfomance summary:
     0,920 ms  _AddCorlibReference                                     1 calls
    19,632 ms  _CollectBundleResources                                 1 calls
    29,646 ms  _CollectColladaAssets                                   1 calls
   143,722 ms  _CollectITunesArtwork                                   1 calls
     1,760 ms  _CollectXamlFiles                                       1 calls
    70,719 ms  _CompileAppManifest                                     1 calls
    30,093 ms  _CompileToNative                                        1 calls
   149,713 ms  _CopyContentToBundle                                    1 calls
     1,335 ms  _CoreCompileColladaAssets                               1 calls

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change Mac OS language and region settings.